# WPF How to subtract two columns of a data base table bounded to DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I want to subtract two columns of a SQL server DB table, to calculate (Remaining Amount=Totalbill-Paid Amount) bounded to DataGrid as below

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalBill}" Header="Total Bill />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PaidAmount}" Header="Bill Amount Paid"/>
```

The above query gives required result when executed in SQL server. But when binding with WPF DataGrid using C#, did not give any out put. please help me

```
con.Open();

string CmdString = "SELECT (si.TotalBill-siph.PaidAmount) from 
SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph inner join SupplyInvoice si on siph.SupplyInvoiceID=si.SupplyInvoiceID";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);           
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory");
sda.Fill(dt1);           
dataGridSupplyOrders.ItemsSource = dt1.DefaultView;

con.Close();
```

Comment: how did you bind the subtraction of two columns to XAML?

Answer (score 0):

in your select Query you have subtracted. and you need to use that column name in DataGridTextColumn.

You want to show only Remaining amount means

your query should like this

```
    SELECT (si.TotalBill-siph.PaidAmount)as RemainingAmount from 
    SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph inner join SupplyInvoice si on 
    siph.SupplyInvoiceID=si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

And your Grid need to add like this

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{RemainingAmount}" Header="RemainingAmount" />
```

You want to show all details means your query should like this

```
    SELECT si.TotalBill as TotalBill, siph.PaidAmount as  PaidAmount ,
     (si.TotalBill-siph.PaidAmount)as RemainingAmount from 
    SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph inner join SupplyInvoice si on 
    siph.SupplyInvoiceID=si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

And your Grid need to add like this

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{TotalBill}" Header="Total Bill" />
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{PaidAmount }" Header="PaidAmount"  />
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{RemainingAmount}" Header="RemainingAmount"/>
```

I hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Than a lot dear. I got my required result.yahooooooo

Comment: Answer is helpful to you? What changes you have done?